# Is there any way I can change my element in css permanently using php or javascript

Tags: php, html, css

How can we make conditional CSS?

**********CSS:

```
if button nepali is clicked   
.english{display :none}
if button english is clicked
.nepali{display :none}
```

---

HTML

```
<tr><td class="invisible"></td></tr>
<tr class="english"><td> 3. And I know that the record which I ma......</td>
</tr><tr class="nepali"><td>३ अनि म जान्दछु............</td></tr>
```

I have 3 buttons on my homepage with which I want to make different language invisible. Buttons will be: 
"English" "Nepali" "Both".
Now I was thinking of a way, "according to the button pressed I want to change my CSS in PHP" so it will display only the language I need. 
I am not good in PHP and I don't know what it can do. For reference you can check this link.

http://www.ldsnepal.tk/

Comment: what did you try? where are you stuck?

Comment: Need some more context here. Are you in control of those 200 html files? I mean, can you write to them? (If so, then why can't you use a text editor to do a global find and replace, but that's another question.) What exactly do you want to change into what? "my element" is a bit vague. And you seem to distinguish between making a change and making a permanent change, which I'm not sure I get.

Comment: So, All my 200 html files are pretty much same. They are text  inside <table> <tr> <td class="hindi">    and other one is <tr><td class ="english">

I have a form in home page of my html that will make a php call. But, I am not sure how can I make my .english {  display: none}   and .hindi {display: none} according to the button pressed in home page of my HTML. 
Also I want to make that change somewhat permenant in a way that when I go to my second page I still want to deactivate my hindi. 
I need some mechanism in may be php but not sure